# Using time.time() in Python - errors don't seem to make sense

Tags: python, variables, time

Using time.time() as a means to schedule a task easily, but for some reason, I keep getting an error which doesn't make a lot of sense to me.  I printed `timenow` and it reads correctly.
Code:

```
 timenow = time.time()
    def my_BidAsk(msg):
        global timenow
        tnow = time.time()
        if (tnow - timenow) >= 60:
            resample()
            timenow = time.time()
```

Here is the error I get, but it doesn't make sense because whether I predefine it or not, globally or locally, the error is still the same.  Any idea why?

```
06-Dec-16 01:09:18 ERROR     Exception in message dispatch.  Handler 'my_BidAsk' for 'tickPrice'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ib/opt/dispatcher.py", line 44, in __call__
    results.append(listener(message))
  File "/Users/usr/Desktop/Hobbies/Coding/connect-contract-order IB.py", line 57, in my_BidAsk
    tnow = time.time()
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'time' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: Have you imported `time`?

Comment: Not importing `time` would raise a different error (`name 'time' is not defined`)

Comment: It runs fine for me under Python3. Using `print(mu_BidAsk("test"))` I get the `timenow` and `tnow` values respectively. Not using the `global` type causes the error you receive. Try running in on an online compiler. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_python_online.php

Comment: @TigerhawkT3, Yes, `time` was imported, as printing `timenow` works fine.  @MichaelMMeskhi, I do understand the need for global variable references since I'm using them within a function.  I'm not sure running the code online will work since my program is used with the IBPy API and receives data from IB, which is when `my_BidAsk` runs.  Using the `time` library works fine in every other way on my computer, just not for this application.  Any other possible ideas for these errors would be great.  Thanks.

Comment: Solved.  Don't know why the solution worked, but it did. `def my_BidAsk(msg):
    global bid
    global ask
    resample()` and I just included the `time` related code at the beginning of the resample function where it evaluates elapsed time and executes the rest of the function `if` more than 60 seconds have passed.  I had successfully done this earlier with `threading.Timer()` which actually did the job with the fewest lines of code, but since `my_BidAsk` runs every time data is received, multiple instances of that object were created and only one executes properly (obviously).

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue which I was able to resolve. In my case, I had a local variable called "time" initialized later in the same function. Using the name of a library as a local variable name causes the exception to be raised when the script runs "t_start = time.time()".

To solve this, I renamed my local variable from "time" to something unoffending (in my case, "time_s"). Ignore any bad pandas practices...

```
t_start = time.time()

for index, row in profile.iterrows():
    time = row['time_s']
    current = row['Current']
    voltage = row['Voltage_V']
    soc = row['SOC']
```

changed to:

```
t_start = time.time()

for index, row in profile.iterrows():
    time_s = row['time_s']
    current = row['Current']
    voltage = row['Voltage_V']
    soc = row['SOC']
```